# cPanel: Django Admin Portal not loading Static/CSS files

Tags: django, django-admin, cpanel, django-staticfiles, django-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Django App on cpanel and the static files for django admin page won't show up but its working fine for the rest of the project.

I even tried to run `python manage.py collectstatic` but it just gives me an error that something's wrong with my manage.py

A little help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)

pip install whitenoise

Comment: Thank you that works like a charm! I just had to add a middleware and static path for whitenoise!